# Is there a way to left join the same table twice with different WHERE statements and create two new fields?

Tags: sql, left-join

I would like to know if it's possible to create a left join twice on the same table with different where statements within them that create a new column so that the data returns 1 row per ID. Example data below:

```
ID | Title | 
123|    1  |
123|    2  |
321|    1  | 
321|    2  |
```

I've tried running this code but it gives me an error

Forgive me, I am new at SQL and am not sure I am even going about this right, but here is what I tried to do:

```
select c.ID, Title1, Title2
From c
left join (select b.title "title1"
from titles b
where title='1' and c.ID=b.ID)
left join (select b.title "title2"
from titles b
where title='2' and c.ID=b.ID)
```

Desired output

```
ID | Title1| Title2 |
123|    1  |  2     |
321|    1  |  2     |
```

Comment: Does the title table hold a foreign key to the book?

Comment: Please provide sample data.  Your code does not have any `join` keys.

Comment: The point of a *table alias* (aka *correlation name*) is to give a unique name to a table value. Learn about them. Use `a` & `b`, not `a` & `a`. Same table twice is called a 'self join'. (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: I am working in a program called Argos that does NOT give error messages or say where the code is wrong. I am also new to writing SQL and am learning the basics and what I need to do is not a simple thing unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select ID, min(title) as title1, max(title) as title2
  from titles 
 group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 alias for the same table

```
select a.ID, a.Title Title1, b.Title Title 2 
from titles a 
inner join  title b on a.id = b.id  and a.Title = 1 and b.title = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this using `left join`:

```
select a.ID, Title1, Title2
From a left join
     titles t1
     on a.id = t1.id and t1.title = '1' left join
     titles t2
     on a.id = t2.id and t2.title = '2' ;
```

It is unclear what you are using for `join` keys between the tables.

Comment: I am matching the IDs on all of the tables, they all contain similar IDs, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it with a LEFT JOIN but you can do it pretty easily with an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Title, b.Title
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Title 
  FROM a
  WHERE Title=1
  ) a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, Title 
  FROM b
  WHERE Title=2
  ) b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

You need a way to join your subqueries together which requires you to keep the ID field in each of the subqueries so it can be used in the JOIN condition.

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I am trying to do-sorry I wasn't super clear but there are three tables in my query-I was trying to oversimplify but there is also a "C"

Comment: You can extend this style by just adding another JOIN, see example below.

`JOIN (
  SELECT ID1, Title 
  FROM c
  WHERE Title=3
  ) c
ON a.ID1 = c.ID1`

Comment: @MelissaM. does that make sense? happy to elaborate more if you need clarification.